# How to rotate imported object in eyeshot?

Tags: rotation, eyeshot

I have an imported step object with Eyeshot. The object is composed of multiple entities, how can I rotate all entities as one?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you tried rotating each one individually and it didn't work as expected right ?

What you did is apply the same rotation to each entity matrix which was a local transformation. You need a world rotation. For that you need to use the override version of the rotate.

Let's say you want a 90 degree rotation on the Z axis of the world on 0,0,0 on ALL entities

```
// create a 90 degree rotation at 0,0,0
var rotation = new Rotation(Math.PI / 2d, Vector3D.AxisZ, new Point3D(0, 0, 0));

// loop each entities and apply the rotation
foreach (var entity in viewportLayout1.Entities)
{
    entity.TransformBy(rotation);
}
```

The axis and point of rotation are very important